# C++ Lock-Free Queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I designed this function, which is used to implement Lock-Free queues, but it has deadlock problems during the actual execution process(dequeue). I checked it many times and I thought it was fine.
I run on the x86 platform and have 12 threads to read and write.

Now I want to figure out what caused the situation, and I want to know if this is a thread-safe design or where it needs to continue to be optimized for higher performance.

12 threads to dequeue and 12 threads to enqueue.
Development tools : Visual studio 2019
I am very much looking forward to your reply. thank u.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#include<atomic>
#include<cassert>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
template<typename T>
class mpmc_queue_t
{
public:
    mpmc_queue_t(size_t size) :
        _size(size),
        _mask(_size - 1),
        _buffer((node_t*)(new aligned_node_t[_size]))
    {
        assert((_size != 0) && ((_size & (~_size + 1)) == _size));
        _read.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        _write.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            _buffer[i].status.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
    ~mpmc_queue_t()
    {
        delete[] _buffer;
    }
    bool enqueue(const T& data)
    {
        auto write = _write.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        node_t* node = &_buffer[write & _mask];
        while (true)
        {
            if (!node->status.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            {
                node->data = data;
                node->status.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
                return true;
            }
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
    bool dequeue(T& data)
    {
        auto read = _read.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        node_t* node = &_buffer[read & _mask];
        while (true)
        {
            if (node->status.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
            {
                data = node->data;
                node->status.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
                return true;
            }
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }

private:
    struct node_t
    {
        T                   data;
        std::atomic_bool    status;
    };
    typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(node_t), std::alignment_of<node_t>::value>::type aligned_node_t;
    typedef char cache_line_pad_t[64];
    cache_line_pad_t    _pad0;
    size_t              _size;
    size_t              _mask;
    node_t* const       _buffer;
    cache_line_pad_t    _pad1;
    std::atomic_size_t  _read;
    cache_line_pad_t    _pad2;
    std::atomic_size_t  _write;
    cache_line_pad_t    _pad3;
};

#define COUNT 100000000
#define THREAD 12
typedef mpmc_queue_t<size_t> queue_t;

template<typename T>
void consumer_func(T* queue)
{
    size_t count = COUNT;
    size_t value = 0;

    while (count > 0) {
        if (queue->dequeue(value)) {
            --count;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "consumer_func ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ok" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void producer_func(T* queue)
{
    size_t count = COUNT;
    while (count > 0) {
        if (queue->enqueue(count)) {
            --count;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "producer_func ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ok" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
long double
run_test(
    T producer_func,
    T consumer_func)
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock_t;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<clock_t> time_t;
    time_t start;
    time_t end;
    start = clock_t::now();
    std::thread producer0(producer_func);
    std::thread producer1(producer_func);
    std::thread producer2(producer_func);
    std::thread producer3(producer_func);
    std::thread producer4(producer_func);
    std::thread producer5(producer_func);
    std::thread producer6(producer_func);
    std::thread producer7(producer_func);
    std::thread producer8(producer_func);
    std::thread producer9(producer_func);
    std::thread producer10(producer_func);
    std::thread producer11(producer_func);

    std::thread consumer0(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer1(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer2(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer3(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer4(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer5(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer6(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer7(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer8(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer9(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer10(consumer_func);
    std::thread consumer11(consumer_func);

    producer0.join();
    producer1.join();
    producer2.join();
    producer3.join();
    producer4.join();
    producer5.join();
    producer6.join();
    producer7.join();
    producer8.join();
    producer9.join();
    producer10.join();
    producer11.join();

    consumer0.join();
    consumer1.join();
    consumer2.join();
    consumer3.join();
    consumer4.join();
    consumer5.join();
    consumer6.join();
    consumer7.join();
    consumer8.join();
    consumer9.join();
    consumer10.join();
    consumer11.join();
    end = clock_t::now();

    return
        (end - start).count()
        * ((double)std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num
            / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den);
}


int main()
{

    {
        queue_t queue(65536);
        long double seconds = run_test(std::bind(&producer_func<queue_t>, &queue),
            std::bind(&consumer_func<queue_t>, &queue));

        std::cout << "The control group completed "
            << COUNT * THREAD
            << " iterations in "
            << seconds
            << " seconds. "
            << ((long double)COUNT * THREAD / seconds) / 1000000
            << " million enqueue/dequeue pairs per second."
            << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: unless your buffer is crazy big, I don't see any way you can be sure that the read or write pointer doesn't wrap all the way around while you're waiting.  Other threads can do a *lot* of enqueues and dequeues during a single call to `yield`

Comment: I'd start with fixing a few general C++ things, like copyability and assignability and compiling with warnings. Further, this class starts its life with a lie using `reinterpret_cast`. Think about what this does here and how the two pointer types actually differ! Then, extract a [mcve] for posting here. Also, describing your strategy using comments would help, both for review but also for understanding and fixing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank u,I changed the code and now it runs directly.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you for your reply,  If the buffer is full, it will not be able to continue writing because each node has a node state, true: readable, false: writable.

Answer (score 1):

This design is not lock-free but "lock-less", because a thread in dequeue may have to wait for an enqueue operation on that item to finish (signaled via `status`), i.e., it does not provide the progress guarantee required by lock-freedom.

As Matt Timmermans already pointed out, there is a problem when indexes wrap around. There is not guarantee that the `status` of the node has already been updated, or, since the operations on `status` are not sequentially consistent, whether this update is visible. This can result in a data race when, after a wrap around, *two* threads (in different rounds) try to push to the same node, because both observed `node->status.load()` returning false.

To solve this, you can use a counter instead of a bool in the node to track the current round the node belongs to (similar to how it's done in this queue by Dmitry Vukov: http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/bounded-mpmc-queue)